# Return a Ruby class name from an instance class that calls method

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I Need to return a class name from a class that calls method f.
How can i do it without inheritance? And... is it possible?!

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

```
class B
  def f
    #need return class A
  end
end

class A
  attr_reader :a
  def initialize()
    @a = B.new
  end
end

A.new.a.f #=> A
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
class B
  def f
    @blabla.class.name
  end
  def initialize(obj)
    @blabla=obj
  end
end
class A
  attr_reader :a
  def initialize()
    @a = B.new(self)
  end
end

A.new.a.f
    => "A"
```

Comment: Could you please prettify your code and remove that IRB noise? :)

Comment: It works, but I was curious to find out a solution without passing an object to initialize. I would not want to initialize an object passing in the instance.

Comment: See my response below: You can reference `A` directly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version of davidrac's solution, except it's using binding.  Sorry for my poor knowledge of binding, here I may use it incorrectly, somebody please then edit it, thx.  Sorry that in my case you still have to pass at least the binding.

```
class B
  def initialize(caller_class)
    @caller_class = caller_class
  end

  def f
    @caller_class
  end
end

class A
  attr_reader :a

  def initialize()
    @a = B.new(self.class)
  end
end

puts A.new.a.f  #=> A
```

Apart from this, I think you can also make use of:

```
set_trace_func lambda { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname| #do sth with classname }
```

or try dirty hack with

```
caller(0).last.match(/:(\d+):/)[1] # get the line number of caller, then get the class
```

But this doesn't work if you call A.new.a.f separately in two lines

Comment: A binding is not the same thing as a class, so you're mixing terminology here. Here's more on bindings: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html

Comment: thanks for correction @GregoryBrown (seacreature) :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to literally return the class `A`, or are you looking to dynamically determine the class of the caller? If the latter, there isn't a safe way to do it without very weird hacks on the Ruby internals, and so it is usually a better idea to change your design to work around this constraint (usually by injecting into the constructor or adding an accessor, as other answers suggest). But if you want to explicitly return the class `A`, it's an easy answer...

Classes are objects in Ruby, stored in constants. Constants within method bodies are not evaluated until the methods are called, so in this case you can simply return `A` from your method:

```
class B
  def f
    A
  end
end

class A
  attr_reader :a
  def initialize()
    @a = B.new
  end
end

A.new.a.f #=> A
```